# Move camera with python to get an object fully in frame

Tags: python

I'm making lots of small 3D objects that I want to render 4 times each with 4 cameras. I know how to set all of this up, but I'm wondering if there is a way (using object bounding box) to have my cameras adjust to the size of the objects in order for them to be well framed without requiring me to tweak each cameras manually.

The cool thing is that all objects are always at world origin, so it shouldn't be too bad to do. I basically need to read object dimension on X,Y,Z, and have my camera move back or forward on it's local axis based on that. Doesn't even need to be 100% perfect. How would you do that?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51563/how-to-automatically-fit-the-camera-to-objects-in-the-view   and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/full-script-for-fitting-the-camera-view-to-the-only-object-in-a-scene  and  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130404/script-to-render-one-object-from-different-angles  and

Comment: Thanks, that should do it!